# Count characters returned from jquery post

Tags: jquery

I have a form that i am using to post command separated values like `1,3,45556,5444` etc.

When i post i am getting the same comma separated value and i am splitting it to access the individual values.

```
$(".sms").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); 
            $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/post.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: $('.sms').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
            var array = data.split(",");

            for (var i in array){
                var count = $(array[i]).length;

                if(count = 10){
                    alert('10 characters');
                }
                if(count = 12){
                    alert('12 characters');
                }
                if(count = 13){
                    alert('13 characters');
                }
                if(count < 10 ){
                    alert('less than 10 characters');
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I am then measuring the length of the individual character and doing something if the value falls into a certain length category.

I have tried this with the following values `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10` and i was expecting all the values to fall under

```
if(count < 10 ){
    alert('less than 10 characters');
}
```

but that is not happening. Any clue why?.

Comment: `=` is for setting a value `==` or `===` is for *comparing* a value. Voting to close as a typo

Comment: Also why would an array of 10 elements ever hit the `count < 10` condition? By its very definition it's `== 10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did this

```
$(".sms").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/post.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('.sms').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var array = data.split(",");

        $(array).each( function(index, value) {
        var str = value.toString();
        var num = str.length;
        var count = parseInt(num);
        if(count == 10){
        console.log('10 characters');
        }
        if(count == 12){
        console.log('12 characters');
        }
        if(count == 13){
        console.log('13 characters');
        }
        if(count < 10 ){
        console.log('less than 10 characters');
        }
         });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all else is working and you are getting data in your response, it looks like this might be the issue:
You use this expression

```
if(count = 12){...}
```

Try this:

```
if(count == 12){...}
```

= is for assignment, whereas == or === is for comparison.

However, if you could do something like console.log(data) in your success callback and share, we will have a better picture of what your data structure looks like in the response.

Comment: If i do that, less than 10 characters is executed but not the 10 characters

Comment: Could you perhaps share what your `data` looks like in your success callback?

Comment: Console log  `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1234567899`